# Replica between Postgres11 and Postgres12

Tags: database-replication, postgresql-11, postgresql-12

I want to setup a replica between 2 different versions of postgres.

Is it possible to setup a replica between pg11(publicator) and pg12(subcriptor)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , definitely.
I tried this once and it worked with no errorors

Comment: Worth to note, that this is only possible with **logical** replication, not with streaming replication